# Samba trigger and script

Tags: samba

I'm wondering if samba implements some kind of scripting, to let me call \my_server\my_dir\my_file from a cliente, where every request to my_dir triggers a script on the server, that executes a database query and returns my_file with the contents of the query result (for example a Bytea field).

Answer (score 1):

The [`magic script`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#MAGICSCRIPT) functionality would probably do what you're looking for. It has always been marked experimental in the documentation, and I've never actually used it, but it's the closest thing to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Evan, I was pointed to this: https://github.com/petere/postgresqlfs looks like what I'm looking for.

Comment: Neat looking tool. I certainly don't see why you couldn't export that filesystem w/ Samba. I'd imagine the performance wouldn't be stellar (as compared to hosting files stored in the filesystem, but it probably isn't horrible either.

Comment: I don't uderstand your last comment, of course I need samba to share that filesystem to Windows users. Initially I tought I could just use Samba and a script, but it looks like I can't, first I need to mount the "pgsql filesystem", then share through Samba.